# Dynamically add a usercontrol in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic, user-controls, windows

I have made a custom UserControl i Vb.net (windows application).

How can I add this dynamically to a form?

Comment: I want to specify how many usercontroles that will be added for each time the program runs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A UserControl is essentially just another class. It inherits from Control, so you can do all kinds of things you do with controls, but otherwise it's just a class. Thus, to add the usercontrol dynamically to your form you'd do the following:

1. Create a new instance of your control. Like `Dim X As New MyControl()`
2. Add the control to your form as a child object to whatever container you want it. Like `Me.MyGreatTabPage.Controls.Add(X)`. You can also add it directly to your form too, because a form is also a container.
3. Set the controls position within the container. That would be setting `X.Location` and `X.Size`.

Remember that each instance you create with `New MyControl()` will be a separate MyControl. Don't make the mistake of repeatedly creating new controls and placing them over each other somehow. Create and place the control once. Assign it to a member variable to your form, and when you need to work with it, use this variable.

Comment: +1 for reminding me to not create the control each time a tab page changes.

Comment: Is there any way to add control of type specified with string instead of creating new instance with its constructor?

Comment: @AreejQadomi - If the number of possibilities is limited, then you could use a `SELECT CASE` statement. Otherwise you need what is known as "reflection". That's a longer story.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is written as: this.Controls.Add(myControl) in C#. I'm sure it's very similar in VB too?

Answer (score 2):

```
Form.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("SomeUserControl.ascx"))
```

Then comes the hard part with trapping *events* in it since it needs to be reloaded every request. I normally use a ViewState flag to signify it's already loaded and the check for the existence of that flag to see if I sould reload it again in OnInit

```
Dim newControl As UserControl = LoadControl("~/Controls/DRQ/Create/UCNewControl.ascx")
Me.panelHolder1.Controls.Add(newControl)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a method for adding two or more:

```
Private _userControlList As New List(Of YourControl)

Private Sub AddingControlOnPanel()
    Dim index As Integer = _userControlList.Count + 1
    Dim userControl As New YourControl
    userControl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(SomeLocation)
    userControl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(SomeSize)
    userControl.Name = "userControl" + index.ToString
    userControl.Visible = False
    _userControlList.Add(userControl)
    UserControlsPanel.Controls.Add(userControl)
    userControl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim tb As New TextBox
        tb.Top = 26 * i
        tb.Left = 12
        tb.Text = "text box " & i.ToString()
        tb.Parent = Me
    Next
```