# Visual Basic - Manage levels for a Maze Game

Tags: vb.net

I thought of creating a small Maze Game with 20 levels and each level will be contained within a User control. From the research that I have done it seems to be the most simple way to handle both the loading and creation for all the levels.

My concern is how User Controls are loaded in memory. My fist thought was to place all of the User Controls - (Maze Game Levels) in my form and set the visibility to False. I then use buttons to make them visible when needed.

Since Visual Basic and Visual Studio is very new to me I have doubts that this is the right way. This seems to be a very tedious process and would love if someone could guide me in the right direction on where I should look for information.

There has been a few YouTube tutorials on this topic, but they never cover the entire game creation, only the one level and the functions to make the game work.

Comment: Not to discourage you, but as you are new to the coding spectrum of VB.NET, I would suggest you do just as your brain tells you to. Until and unless you DIY you won't reach to an elegant solution. Tutorials are there to help you out with the logic. Rest is upon you.

Comment: I never ever thought of it this way. Your answer can be applied to other things in life as well... hehe, Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: For example on https://mva.microsoft.com/ is a bunch of training videos that may be useful.

Comment: Glad you took it positively :) , but my comment wasn't a solution for what you asked. Anyways, make as many mistakes as you want now, correct and learn from them. Later on everything would seem plausible and within your reach \m/

Comment: The [ASP.NET](http://asp.net/) site is a good place to start - there's all sorts on there.  Technically this isn't really a good question for this site, however, as we would expect you to nip off and have a look for tutorials yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an answer to my question after a couple of hours of research.

See: [Dynamic User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374082/dynamically-add-a-usercontrol-in-vb-net)